# making a directory and then cd'ing in it directly without a new command

Tags: ios, bash

So I am making a Bash Script to make a timestamp directory but the problem I am facing is that it makes a timestamp directory but doesn't cd's into it here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%S")
mkcd () {
   mkdir "$now"
   cd "$now"
}
mkdir /var/mobile/backup
cd /var/mobile/backup
mkcd /var/mobile/backup/$now
echo yep
```

by the way this script is for ios

Comment: Try changing cd "$now" to cd "$!"

Comment: cd in a script have no effect on your shell because the script run in a different shell. You have to use full path to create directory.

Comment: creating full path didnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

Update after @dash-o's comment,

Current working directory is a process attribute (like environment variables) each process has it's own, a simple command in a shell starts a new process and waits for termination to update exit status `$?`variable. Child process have it's own environment variable set inheriting exported variables of parent process.
The current working directory of child process can be changed but will not change parent working directory.
`cd` is not a program but a shell built-in.

Comment: The current wording directory is an attribute of the process. Most Shells (bash included) will expose the working directory as (environment) variable as convenience, but other programs (binaries, or other scripts) may not always follow this rule

Comment: @dash-o, it's more correct indeed, i wanted to say that it was linked to a process as information provided through /proc/pid special files (but environ is a snapshot of variables when the process started)

Answer (score 0):

As @edvin already said, this script runs on a different shell and have no effect on your current session PWD.

You could write this script in your user's `.profile` or shell-specific file as a **function**. This way calling the function will not create a new shell instance to execute your commands but will execute them in current shell:

```
mkcd() {
  mkdir $1 && cd $1
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%S")
mkcd $now
```

Comment: wrote but didnt help

Comment: @GurjotSingh, Is this function become visible in your shell? If not, what shell and OS you're using? Could be that `.profile` file is not used by your shell. I tested on OSX with bash in Terminal app and it works.

Comment: export PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games'
export PS1='\h:\w \u\$ '
umask 022

for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        . $i
    fi
done
mkcd() {
  mkdir $1 && cd $1
}

Comment: @GurjotSingh, are you sure you removed/renamed your initial script? It have the same name and could interfere with this function in profile. Other idea: change `mkcd()` to `function mkcd` in profile and try again in new shell.

Comment: yes i am sure i dont know why its not working @Krin-San

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this is to use `$_`, which basically represents the *last argument of the preceding command*.

```
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%S")
mkcd () {mkdir $now && cd $_}
```

As a sidenote I would put the `now` variable inside the function, so that `mkcd` does not depend on variables created outside of the function itself

```
mkcd () {
    now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%S")
    mkdir $1$now && cd $_
}
```

Example call:

```
mkcd ~/
```

This creates a directory `/home/yourusername/2017-07-07-27` for example.

Comment: This mkcd() function implementation is not flexible: there is no way to choose a folder name without editing script. I think, moving `now` variable out of the function and calling `mkcd $now` will be better.

Comment: I have modified the function to accept an arbitrary destination for the directory that has to be created. However, I do not see how moving `now` out of the function will yield any benefit over creating it inside the function.